# NodeJS of Azure Function is much more slower than local nodeJS

Tags: node.js, function, azure, azure-functions

I'm beginner at nodeJs and Azure.

I'm trying to use wav-encoder npm module in my program.
[wav-encoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wav-encoder)

so I wrote code like below,

```
var WavEncoder = require('wav-encoder');

const whiteNoise1sec = {
    sampleRate: 40000,
    channelData: [
        new Float32Array(40000).map(() => Math.random() - 0.5),
        new Float32Array(40000).map(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
    ]
};

WavEncoder.encode(whiteNoise1sec).then((buffer)=>{
    console.log(whiteNoise1sec);
    console.log(buffer);
});
```

It runs on my local machine, less than 2 secs.

but if I upload similar code to Azure Functions, it takes more than 2 mins.

below is code in my Functions. It is triggered by http REST call.

```
var WavEncoder = require('wav-encoder');

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    const whiteNoise1sec = {
        sampleRate: 40000,
        channelData: [
            new Float32Array(40000).map(() => Math.random() - 0.5),
            new Float32Array(40000).map(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
        ]
    };

    WavEncoder.encode(whiteNoise1sec).then((buffer)=>{
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: whiteNoise1sec
        };

        context.done();
    });

};
```

Do you know how can I improve performance of Azure?

---

## Update

```
context.res = {
    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
    body: whiteNoise1sec
};

context.done();
```

I found that this line cause slow performance.

If I give large size array to `context.res.body` it takes long time when I call `context.done();`

Isn't large size json response proper for Azure Functions???

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to analyze performance issues like this, but there are few things to consider here and few things to look at.

**Cold functions vs warm functions performance**

if the function hasn't been invoked in a while or never (I think it's about 10 or 20 minutes) it goes idle, meaning it gets deprovisioned. next time you hit that function it needs to be loaded from storage. Due to some architecture and relying of a certain type of storage, IO hits for small files are bad currently. There is work in progress to improve that, but a large npm tree would cause > 1 minute loading time just to fetch all the small js files. if the function is warm however, it should be in the msec range (*or depending on the work your function is doing, see below for more*)

**Workaround**: use this to pack your function https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-pack

**Slower CPU for consumption sku**

in consumption sku, you are scaled to many instances (in the hundreds) but each instance is affinitized to a single core. That is fine for IO bound operations, regular node functions (since they are single threaded anyway), etc. But if your function tries to utilize CPU for CPU bound workloads, it's not going to perform as you expect it.

**Workaround**: you can use dedicated Skus for CPU bound workloads

Comment: Thanks for reply and useful information, but it seems like that in my case, low performance is caused for large size of JSON in response and request.
I solve this issue by making arrays as blob binary. If JSON structure of req and res is not big, performance is not so low.
It seems like that parsing request and response in azure is slow.